# Jquery mobile dynamic fields not applying styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Hi i have creates a html page that creates dynamic fields and when i add them to the listview, it doesnt apply the jquery mobile themes.

here is my javascript:

```
//Dynamically load data fields for items
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#claimPagefields', function(){ 
    //trigger a create event
    $('#claimPagefield').trigger('create');
    loadFields();
});
```

Here is my HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title></title>
<link href="src/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/jquery.mobile.iscrollview-pull.css" />
<script src="src/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="src/iscroll.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js"></script>
<script src="src/script/itemFields.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css" /> 
  <script src="src/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="src/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="claimPagefields">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-tap-toggle="false" data-transition="none" > <a href="" onclick="history.back(-1); return false;">Back</a>
    <h1>New Claim</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul class="ui-li" data-role="listview" id="claimTypelistfields" data-inset="true"  data-scroll="true">
      <li data-role="list-divider">
        <h2 id="itemTitle">Title</h2>
      </li>


    </ul>
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="some.html" data-theme="b">Save</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesnt apply the theme on the input fields itself which typically look like this when i am adding it

```
 listItem = '<li id="reasons">' +
        '<h3>Reasons:</h3>' +
        '<div data-role="fieldcontain">' +
          '<input type="text" name="reasons" id="textFieldReasons" value="" />' +
        '</div>' +
      '</li>';

         $('#claimTypelistfields').append(listItem);

         $('#claimTypelistfields').listview('refresh');
```

If i manually add this snippet of code to the above input field manually

```
style="width:100%"
```

It works and resizes the width only but i am trying to see if there is way to apply it once instead of having to apply the themes all manually for each field!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is because:

```
$('#claimTypelistfields').listview('refresh');
```

will enhance only listview widget and only it. Every non-listview widget added to a listview will not be enhanced.

Basically you will make it work if you use this line:

```
$('#claimPagefield').trigger('pagecreate');
```

after the content has been added.

One more thing, in your current code, this line:

```
$('#claimPagefield').trigger('create');
```

will not do anything, mainly because you are calling it before new content is appended and second thing, because **`#claimPagefield`** is a page id you must use **`pagecreate`** instead of **`create`**. **`Create`** works only on content div.

Comment: Hi thanks for the tips. i tried Create after i called loadFields(); and it did not apply the theme on the input fields. i then tried the pageCreate that replaced the create trigger and same issue, the input fields or radio buttons do not have a theme applied to it. The text however does have a theme applied to it ie the <h3>Reasons:</h3> tag

Comment: Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Phhh7/ , tell me do you use a loop to add new dynamic content?

Comment: No. i use a bunch of If statements to add content. This is getting more odd. i basically copied my whole JS code to the example you provided and just changed the pageID name on the pageCreate trigger and it works on your example. however, when i revery back to the appropriate pageID and try it from a browser it fails and doesnt apply the theme.I also see that although your code works it doesnt add the dividers in the list items and it appears as one whole list item in the ui

Comment: If you want mail me your project and I will fix it. It is probably something easy but I need a better perspective.

Comment: We can initiate a private chat. i dont know how to though?

Comment: To be hones I also dont know but let as continue talking, application will offer us a private chat soon.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33538/discussion-between-gajotres-and-jonney)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

this code below did the trick as you need to first refrsh and then call teh create trigger all in one line

```
$('#claimProfileListView').listview('refresh').trigger("create");
```